# Trial Division Prime Generator

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, primes

```
import math


def generate_primes(limit):
    """Generates and prints a list of primes up to a given limit"""
    prime_list = [2, 3]
    num = 5
    increment_2 = True  # When True increment by 2. When False increment by 4

    while num <= limit:
        is_prime = True
        sqr_lim = math.sqrt(num)
        for x in prime_list:
            # Loop through list of prime numbers and check divisibility
            if x > sqr_lim:
                break
            if num % x == 0:
                is_prime = False
                break

        if is_prime:
            # Add primes to list to only check prime numbers
            prime_list.append(num)

        # Alternate step size between 2 and 4 to skip multiples of 2 and 3
        if increment_2:
            num += 2
            increment_2 = False
        else:
            num += 4
            increment_2 = True

    print(prime_list)
    return prime_list


def main():
    generate_primes(200)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I'm writing a program to generate a list of prime numbers to a given limit through the use of trial division. I was wondering if there is a way to further optimize this code. Currently it: skips multiples of 2 and 3; stores primes in a list and the list is used to check for primality; and checks divisibility up until the square root of the number it's analyzing.

I would also appreciate it if someone could critique me on my coding style such as comments, white space, and organization because I know its pretty rough around the edges. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I’ve rolled back your most recent edit.  You cannot update the question to include feedback given in the answers, below, as that invalidates the answers.  See [what can I do when someone answers](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers), especially the “what should I **not** do” section.

Answer (score 1):

The function `generate_primes()` shouldn’t print the list it generated.  The caller should print the returned value, if desired.

---

Calling `generate_primes(2)` will unexpectedly return `[2, 3]`, as will `generate_primes(1)` or `generate_primes(-500)`.

---

The `increment_2` flag is awkward.  When `True`, increment by 2 seems ok, but when `False` the increment is ... what?  0?  1?

Instead of an `increment_2` flag, you could use an `increment` amount, starting with 2 ...

```
increment = 2
```

... and then toggle that value between 2 & 4:

```
num += increment

# Alternate step size between 2 and 4
increment = 6 - increment
```

No more `if ... else ...`, reducing the complexity of the function slightly.

---

Stretch goal:

After `generate_primes(200)`, if a call is made to `generate_primes(500)`, you will recalculate all of the primes beneath 200.  Perhaps there is a way to cache the computed values for future generate calls?

Comment: Caching the primes and computed values should be simple enough, but I'm mostly looking for other ways to optimize the code. Either the square root function or increments would be a good place to start in my opinion. However, trial division has its limits and I would be glad if you or someone else could point me another direction to approach this problem in.

Comment: The [sieve of Eratosthenes](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sieve-of-eratosthenes) is a good next step in prime number generation.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`else` feature of loops](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops), which gets executed iff no `break` statement was executed. This gets rid of your flag variable:

```
while num <= limit:
    sqr_lim = math.sqrt(num)
    for x in prime_list:
        # Loop through list of prime numbers and check divisibility
        if x > sqr_lim:
            break
        if num % x == 0:
            break
    else:
        # Add primes to list to only check prime numbers
        prime_list.append(num)
```

However, this would mean that the condition that breaks the loop because you have reached the square limit would avoid this from being triggered.

To avoid this, you could have a look at the [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) module, which provides the [`takewhile` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile):

```
for p in takewhile(lambda p: p <= sqr_lim, prime_list):
    if num % p == 0:
        break
else:
    prime_list.append(num)
```

Your variable increment also boils down to the observation that all prime numbers larger than 3 are of the form `6k + 1` or `6k + 5` with `k = 0, 1, ...`. This is for the same reason you used the variable increment, all numbers of the form `6k + 0, 2, 4` are divisible by two and all numbers of the form `6k + 3` by three.

You could use this with the [`itertools` recipe `roundrobin`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#recipes) to generate all candidate numbers.

> ```
> from itertools import cycle, islice
>
> def roundrobin(*iterables):
>     "roundrobin('ABC', 'D', 'EF') --> A D E B F C"
>     # Recipe credited to George Sakkis
>     num_active = len(iterables)
>     nexts = cycle(iter(it).__next__ for it in iterables)
>     while num_active:
>         try:
>             for next in nexts:
>                 yield next()
>         except StopIteration:
>             # Remove the iterator we just exhausted from the cycle.
>             num_active -= 1
>             nexts = cycle(islice(nexts, num_active))
> ```

```
candidates = roundrobin(range(7, limit, 6),  # 6k + 1, k = 1, 2, ...
                        range(5, limit, 6))  # 6k + 5, k = 0, 1, ...
for num in candidates:
    ...
```

However, if you want to get all primes up to some large(ish) number, sieves are really hard to beat. The easiest one to implement is the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes), which can for example be done like this:

```
def prime_sieve(limit):
    prime = [True] * limit
    prime[0] = prime[1] = False

    for i, is_prime in enumerate(prime):
        if is_prime:
            yield i
            for n in range(i * i, limit, i):
                prime[n] = False
```

If you need even more speed, you could take a look at the [Sieve of Atkin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Atkin). However, using the above implementation of the Sieve of Eratosthenes, I can generate all primes up to 100.000.000 in less than 30 seconds, which is usually fast enough.

Comment: Just a typo: "executed iff no break ", ``` iff -> if```. Too few characters for me to propose an edit (min 6)

Comment: @Abdur-RahmaanJanhangeer That's no typo! [It is mathematical shorthand for "if, and only if"](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_and_only_if). Here I thought it was not important enough that I write it out, but the `else` can only not be executed if there was a `break` and no other way (except for an exception halting the whole program).